# Formula Cell value is not updating in the reference while Using Google Spreadsheet API with JAVA

Tags: java, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have this sample code in which I am trying to integrate google spreadsheet API with java.

```
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.CellEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;

public class ExpressionExample {

    public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME = "xxxx@gmail.com";

    public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = "xxx";

    private static URL cellFeedUrl;

    public static final String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/1QWX-zOkBe36M7oC9sn6z8ZuccGt7Wg-IFwtynn379kM";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(
                "Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");

        service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME,
                GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

        URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);

        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl,
                SpreadsheetEntry.class);

        WorksheetEntry sheet = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets()
                .get(0));

        cellFeedUrl = spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0).getCellFeedUrl();

        CellEntry cellA1 = new CellEntry(1, 1, "3");
        CellEntry cellB1 = new CellEntry(1, 2, "high mech");

        String line = "=IF(A1<5,IF(B1={\"high mech\",\"low mech\",\"mid mech\"},10,IF(B1=\"electronic\",20,0)),IF(A1>=5,IF(B1=\"electronic\",40,0),0)) ";
        CellEntry cellc1 = new CellEntry(1, 3, line);

        service.insert(cellFeedUrl, cellA1);
        service.insert(cellFeedUrl, cellB1);
        service.insert(cellFeedUrl, cellc1);

        System.out.println(cellc1.getCell().getValue());
        System.out.println(cellc1.getCell().getNumericValue());
        System.out.println(cellc1.getCell().getDoubleValue());
    }

}
```

When I am running the code 
I am getting this value.

null
null
NaN

I want the value of cell C1. it is showing the correct value in google spreadsheet. I am not able to read it in my code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCell()` only reads the local information about the cell, i.e. the stuff you inserted.
You'll have to get the cell again from a `CellFeed`, then go through the entries to find you cell again to read back the online information.

```
service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
for(CellEntry ce : cellFeed.getEntries()) {
  Cell cell = ce.getCell();
  if(cell.getRow() == 1 && cell.getCol() == 3) {
    System.out.println(cell.getDoubleValue());
  }
}
```